# Removing special characters from @hapi/joi error messages

Tags: node.js, joi

I'm using Joi from @hapi/joi to validate my data, but when I try to customize the error messages by removing the backward slashes and the double quotes; it doesn't work.

**My validation function**

```
const validateSignup = (user) => {

  const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    first_name: Joi.string().min(3).max(20)
      .required(),
    last_name: Joi.string().min(3).max(20)
      .required(),
    email: Joi.string().email({ minDomainSegments: 2 }).trim().required(),
    password: Joi.string().regex(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$/)
      .required()

  });

  const options = {
    abortEarly: false,
    key: '"{{key}}" ',
    escapeHtml: true,
    language: {
      string: {
          base: '{{key}} '
      }
  }
};
  return schema.validate(user, options);
};
```

I tried to search online but for some reason, it's not working. What am I doing wrong? Please, help.

**Postman's response**

[image: Response body]

Comment: This seems an old issue in joi. Have a look at here: https://github.com/AndrewKeig/express-validation/issues/28   Express-validator is a good option with really good custom error support.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Customizing error message in @hapi/joi to remove double quote is available after this release https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/2262. Default `label:'"'`. Though this feature is available, you may not get typings for it till https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/hapi__joi/v/16.0.12, hope they will add soon.

```
    const options = {
      errors: {
        wrap: {
          label: ''
        }
      }
    };

    return schema.validate(user, options);
```

In your case, the above configuration removes the double quote.

[Here is the output without double quote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrY0r.png)

Comment: Thx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @sarojrana answer you can also use:

```
  const options = {
      errors: {
        wrap: {
          label: false
        }
      }
    };

    return schema.validate(user, options);
```

And also set this to be the default for all schemas using:

```
// set label false as default for all schemas
const JoiInstance = Joi.defaults(schema => {
  return schema.options({
    errors: {
      wrap: {
        // Remove quotes from variable names in error messages
        label: false
      }
    }
  });
});
```

and then use `JoiInstance` instead of `Joi`:

```
  const schema = JoiInstance.object().keys({
    first_name: Joi.string().min(3).max(20)
      .required(),
    last_name: Joi.string().min(3).max(20)
      .required(),
    email: Joi.string().email({ minDomainSegments: 2 }).trim().required(),
    password: Joi.string().regex(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$/)
      .required()

  });
```